# active_admin/formtastic ignoring polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, formtastic, activeadmin

I'm currently having trouble with the form for a polymorphic association in active_admin in Ruby on Rails.

I have three models set up: offices, companies and users. Both companies and users can own an office. My models are set up as follows:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ownable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices, :as => :ownable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices, :as => :ownable
end
```

active_admin doesn't allow me to edit the owner on its forms, but does show it correctly on the index and show pages (including links to the company or user).

I've tried playing with formtastic to manually create the form but have not had any luck - the "ownable" fields just get ignored and everything else renders properly.

To be clear: I want to be able to edit the owner of the Office model on the new and edit fields in active_admin.

Can anyone offer any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this is like a month late, but I came across your question when I was looking for answers to a different one I had.

I've been working with ActiveAdmin and polymorphic relationships in my project.

I would suggest this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Office do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs :ownable_type, :ownable_id
    f.buttons
  end
```

When a model is polymorphic, there are two fields that need to be configured which point to the object that it has a relationship with. So, in this case, you need fields for the type of owner (User or Company) and the id of the object.

This should allow you to edit those fields on a particular Office.

Comment: This shows a field for both the *type and *id, but it shows them as textfields (as opposed to the drop down that's given for normal associations) which is kind of a bummer.

Comment: Also, specifying the fields this way breaks the model introspection that's used to display all fields on the form, which is quite annoying.